# Chrome Headless is not recognized as Google Chrome on WebSite

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I noticed that the ChromeDriver in Headless mode does not receive the default Profile that I created, and for this project it is necessary because I need the cookies and sessions always saved .. searching I found some topics that said Chrome in Headless mode does not accept preferences. It is true?

Another thing I noticed in Headless mode is that some sites do not identify ChormeDriver like Google Chrome, which is pretty weird. Is there any way to force this in Chrome Options?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: regarding headless mode problem, it could be due to this limitation: https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol/issues/83. But it depends on site. With so little info hard to say